# Public subnet routing

Tags: routing, centos7

I have one public IP from my ISP 198.51.100.123/21 and a public 203.0.113.1/29 subnet routed by my ISP through the first IP. 
OS: CentOS 7.

I want to assign each IP from the /29 subnet to a virtual NIC. How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Care to share a bit more about your setup? Is your server the only thing connected to the router? Is there a Firewall?

Comment: The server is directly connected to the ISP equipment, which they told me that is a bridge, via ethernet cable with the ip 123.123.123.123.

Comment: I suggest you check the relevant CentOS documentation and then come back here if you have specific issues. The question as is looks too much like a "do my homework" question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question requires some understanding of IP routing. First you need to verify that the ISP routes the IP block to the public IP address of your linux server -- which it apparently does. Next you need to enable routing on your linux server so that it can handle the packets it receives on its public interface destinated for different networks.

Finally, you can create loopback interfaces for each public IP address using the method [described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444124/how-to-add-a-loopback-interface).

Edited to expand on the answer as per the comments below.

Comment: A lookback is NOT reachable outside the host. The OP has public IP addresses, so realistically he needs those to be reachable from the Internet.

Comment: On my Cisco router the loopback addresses are reachable given that routing is in place, e.g. my router needs to advertise the loopback IP addresses using a routing protocol or - which is the case here - the other router needs to configure a static route towards my router. And he sais so himself that his ISP routes the block towards his public server.

Comment: Well, sure if IP routing / forwaring is enabled then you can easily reach any non directly connected interface. But the CentOS host is not guaranteed to be configure with IP forwarding enabled, and honestly I think is a bit overkill to configure a server as a "router" just to be reachable via the Internet.

Comment: You can't configure the public IP addresses from the second range on your eth0 interface so you will have to use some other mechanism. Why not configure it as a router if you want it to listen to several IP addresses from different ranges on a single interface? If you want to talk about overkill, perhaps assigning 9 public IP addresses to a single server can be considered overkill as well. By default it's not configured for IP routing but that's not too hard to do.

Comment: You're right, thats why I asked more info about his setup. It can be that the ISP gives him a router to which he need to connect (so he needs to address only the `/29` LAN). If he needs a router too, and he wants to use his CentOS server as a router, he should update his answer. The OP explicitly asked "I want to assign each IP from the /29 subnet to a virtual NIC. How can I do that?"

Comment: And I provide an answer to his question. loopback interfaces are virtual NICs. And he states in his question that his ISP routes the /29 to his first public IP address, which belongs to the server.

Comment: I agree, please edit your answer so I can remove the downvote (it won't let me unless you do an edit). Still, I think this stands for the OP: "I suggest you check the relevant CentOS documentation and then come back here if you have specific issues. The question as is looks too much like a "do my homework" question." :D

Comment: @MrShunz: Done. Is the answer better now?

Answer (score 1):

You may edit `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-e*` (whatever it is named on your system) and add the additional IP addresses. For example:

```
IPADDR=198.51.100.123
PREFIX=21
IPADDR2=203.0.113.1
PREFIX2=29
IPADDR3=203.0.113.2
PREFIX3=29
IPADDR4=203.0.113.3
PREFIX4=29
IPADDR5=203.0.113.4
PREFIX5=29
IPADDR6=203.0.113.5
PREFIX6=29
```

Comment: Will that work correctly when you try to source traffic from these IP addresses?

Comment: @Tom If you actually use one as a source address, then traffic will pass back and forth as you would expect.

Comment: Then I like this solution more than my own. And I'm sure @MrShunz would too.